# PHP not parsing JSON as i want it

Tags: php, json, vue.js

I have a hobby project that provides an api to access, everything works fine on other ends, the thing is that i need the json array to not have brackets so i can separate the object in the array.

This is the url that provided the json : 
https://cryptoapi.news/api/v1/free/lastnews/all/10

But if you look at this api for example : 
https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json

it has no brackets in the object, that [] brackets before article array are stoping me from acessing the object in vue.js

I am pushing on my api end point this elements to an empty array :

```
             $json = array(
             "article" => array(
                          "article_id" => "$idx",
                          "article_title" => "$title",
                          "article_content" => "$content",
                          "article_date" => "$date",
                          "article_image" => "$image",
                          "article_coin" => "$coinx",
                          "article_source" => $src
             ));

             array_push($main, $json);

             //$json = array_values($json);
```

then providing the json as this :

```
$js = json_encode($main, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
print_r($js);
```

I just need to remove that brackets and it ill make the object acessible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the object you create to be in an array, then **don't put it in an array**!.

Remove `array_push($main, $json);`, then `json_encode` the `$json` variable.